# How do I call a result of tinker or fiddle?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage

A person who tinkers is a tinkerer (and fidler is fiddling), but how do I call a result or product (noun) of fiddling or tinkering? Also fiddling or tinkering?  Fiddlery/Tinkery? But looks like such word doesn't exists - Google shows no meaningful results for "tinkery" or "fiddlery".

Comment: What, like a doodad?

Comment: Yea, or a work which was complicated and unnecessary or was done inefficiently (that would more a result of tinkering than fiddling)

Comment: You can use the -ing form for both the action and the result. "Her fiddling is masterful" or "Your tinkerings are cluttering up the house" etc.

Comment: Long live gerund nouns. They are a useful tools.

Comment: [*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fidler)fiddler

Comment: Is "[thingamabob](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/thingamabob)" at all close to what you're looking for? or is "[contraption](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/contraption)" perhaps closer to what you mean?

Comment: Perhaps -- seeing as how it was _complicated and unnecessary_ -- it would be a [Rube Goldberg machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rube_Goldberg_machine)?

Comment: This is hard to answer.  I can fiddle with something for 2 hours, and leave it basically unchanged.  Or I can tinker with a problem and create a Rube Goldberg machine (as @RogerSinasohn) or jury-rig a solution.

Comment: A Rube Goldberg machine is specifically a very complicated machine that performs a simple task. I'm not sure if it's required or not, but it's also implied that it takes more work to set the machine back up for the next use after each use than it would be to manually do the task that the machine is designed to accomplish. e.g. a line of dominoes along a windowsill to a weight that upon falling pulls a string that releases a ball bearing that knocks down more dominoes along a bookshelf that ...[use your imagination to add more absurdity here]... to eventually flip on a light switch.

Comment: In IT we called it a kludge.  The Oxford's online dictionary defines it as "A machine, system, or program that has been badly put together, especially a clumsy but temporarily effective solution to a particular fault or problem."

Comment: What about discombobulation?

Comment: @bookmanu: "Discombobulation" isn't a physical item, it's a feeling of being out of place and disconcerted or confused. You can't 'fiddle with' or 'tinker on' a discombobulation.

Comment: First please understand that one who tinkers is a tinker; who fiddles is a fiddler.

After accepting that, what else are you asking, please?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin 1006a already gave an answer https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/457525/how-do-i-call-a-result-of-tinker-or-fiddle?noredirect=1#comment1101333_457525

Comment: Your link english.stackexchange.com/questions/457525/… comes back to this very thread.

Why is it hard to accept that one who tinkers is a tinker; who fiddles is a fiddler? After accepting that, what else are you asking, please?

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you are looking for [fine-tuned](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fine-tuned)

> 1 : *precisely adjusted for the highest level of performance, efficiency, or effectiveness a fine-tuned machine*
>
> His voice on "Always Late with Your Kisses" rolled along its cordillera of syllables like a fine-tuned sports car. —Bryan Di Salvatore
>
> 2 : *improved or refined over time*
>
> His story is that of a man with an exquisitely fine-tuned creative imagination … —Bruce McCall
> It is one of the many recipes that are treasured family hand-downs or the fine-tuned ideas of Marilyn Lewis … —Caroline Bates

Comment: Perhaps I forgot to mention it's supposed to be pejorative, fine-tuning sounds like a good thing ;)

Comment: fine-tuning isn't the same as tinkering